# Convert vCard Bulk Contact File to Single .vcf files

Tags: php, vcf-vcard

I recently had an issue... I wanted to transfer my contacts fro my LG U990 Viewty to my iPhone 3GS

I exported the contacts from my LG to a vCard File containing all the addresses all in one as

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N;CHARSET=UTF-8:A;
TEL;CELL;CHARSET=UTF-8:*121#
REV:20120720T081000Z
END:VCARD
```

Now the above format repeated itself for all contacts... in that single file...

I wanted to convert this single file to original vcf files... not knowing that they could not be imported to iPhone also :(

Actualy Solution : I needed to upload the original bulk vCard file to a new gmail's accounts contacts and sync my contacts to that list in iTunes... which finally I did

However, I made this code which is in PHP generally available as a paid software which people buy to decipher the contacts... here is the below code... FREE

contacts.txt is that file ... open that vCard file in text editor and copy the contents and make this contacts.txt file

```
$filename = "contacts.txt";
$fd = fopen ($filename, "r");
$contents = fread ($fd,filesize ($filename));

fclose ($fd);
$delimiter = "BEGIN:VCARD";
$splitcontents = explode($delimiter, $contents);
$counter = "";
$write = "";
$finalName = "";

foreach ( $splitcontents as $color )
{
    $counter = $counter+1;
    $first = strpos($color, "UTF-8:");
    $second = strpos($color, "TEL;");
    $name = substr($color, $first+6, $second-$first-7);

    $wordChunks = explode(";", $name);

    for($i = 0; $i < count($wordChunks); $i++)
    {
        if(trim($wordChunks[0])!="" || trim($wordChunks[1])!="" )
            $finalName .= " ".$wordChunks[$i];
    }

    $finalName= trim($finalName);   
    $fileName = $finalName.".vcf";

    $ourFileHandle = fopen($fileName, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    $stringData = "BEGIN:VCARD ".$color;
    fwrite($ourFileHandle, $stringData);
    fclose($ourFileHandle);

    $finalName = "";

}
```

this will finally make miltuple .vcf files of format given above...

**MY QUESTION : WHAT I DID WAS VERY SIMPLE AND HAS LOOPHOLES - CAN WE DO THE ABOVE ITERATION AND FILTERING IN A PHP REGULAR EXPRESSION ?**

it would be a great learning ?

Comment: What do you mean with "A PHP REGULAR EXPRESSION"? One expression? No foreach loop? No inner for loop?
I wonder about all the stuff you're doing in your code. Isn't it easier just to split after the END:VCARD ?

Comment: Might be its easier that way... that is why I said it had loopholes... I mean a preg_replace expression filter etc...

Answer (score 1):

1. Read the file and get a string of the context

   ```
   NSData *String_Data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:yourfilepath];
   NSString *theString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:String_Data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   ```
2. Get array of all the lines in the context

   ```
   NSArray *lines = [theString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
   ```
3. Run for Loop through each line: Check prefix for BEGIN: or END:

   ```
   NSString * stringForVCard=@"";
   for (int i=0; i<[lines count];i++){
   [stringForVCard stringByAppendingString:[lines objectAtIndex:i]
   if ([line hasPrefix:@"END"]) 
   [stringForVCard writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Make your own file path for each VCF"] atomically:TRUE encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil ];
   //Empty the string
   stringForVCard=@"";}
   ```

Comment: @foxybagga
I've the same issue, I want to Convert vCard Bulk Contact File to Single .vcf files, but I'm not sure how utilize the given code, is it mandatory that I must have PHD, can't I do it another way?

Answer (score 0):

*file structure:*

index.php

contacts.vcf

a(folder)

```
$filename = "contacts.vcf";
$file = file($filename);
$i=1;
$content = "";
foreach ( $file as $line )
{
    if($line == 'BEGIN:VCARD'."\r\n"){
        $content = "";
    }
    $content .= $line;
    if($line == 'END:VCARD'."\r\n"){
        $fileName = $i.".vcf";
        $ourFileHandle = fopen('a/'.$fileName, 'w') or die("can't open file");
        fwrite($ourFileHandle, $content);
        fclose($ourFileHandle);
        $i++;
        echo '<br>' . $i .'
';
    }
}
```